On a non-standard application of Kalman filter
These questions arose when I was reading Online Appendix D for the paper Missing Events in Event Studies: Identifying the Effects of Partially-Measured News Surprises by R.S. Gurkaynak, B. Kisacikoglu and J.H. Wright.
From what I have learnt, the usual exercise of Expectation-maximization with kalman filter is an iterative repetition of

E-step: based on the estimates of parameters from the last M-step, use kalman filter to update the estimates of the latent variable;

M-step: use the estimates of latent variable from the E-step to get new estimates of parameters.


In the paper cited above, however, the authors seem to use EMKF algorithm  to estimate the parameters with one single M-step.
Specifically, the authors aim to uncover the latent variable $f_t$ in the equation $$y_t=\beta's_t+\gamma d_tf_t+\varepsilon_t,$$
where $y_t$ is an $n\times1$ vector, $s_t$ is a $K\times1$ vector, which are observed without error, $d_t$ is a dummy that is $1$ if there is an event at time $t$ or $0$ otherwise, $f_t$ is an iid $N(0,\sigma_f^2)$ latent variable, $\beta$ is a $K\times n$ matrix, $\gamma$ is an $n\times1$ vector, and $\varepsilon_t$ is iid with mean zero and diagonal variance-covariance matrix of $\Sigma_\varepsilon.$
The log-likelihood function is as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}l(\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}\Sigma_{t=1}^{T}\mathbf{1}(d_{t}=1)\{(y_{t}-\beta^{\prime}s_{t})^{\prime}(\Sigma_{\varepsilon}+\gamma\gamma^{\prime})^{-1}(y_{t}-\beta^{\prime}s_{t})\\&+\log(|\Sigma_{\varepsilon}+\gamma\gamma^{\prime}|)\}\\&+\mathbf{1}(d_{t}=0)\{y_{t}^{\prime}\Sigma_{\varepsilon}^{-1}y_{t}+\log(|\Sigma_{\varepsilon}|)\}\end{aligned}.$$
To identify the parameters, the authors solve the following system of equations, which is obtained by maximize the log-likelihood function:
$$\beta=E(\mathbf{1}(d_t=1)s_ts_t^{\prime})^{-1}E(\mathbf{1}(d_t=1)s_ty_t^{\prime}),$$
$$\Sigma_{\varepsilon}=E(y_{t}^{\prime}y_{t}\mathbf{1}(d_{t}=0)),$$ $$\gamma\gamma^{\prime}=E((y_{t}-\beta^{\prime}s_{t})^{\prime}(y_{t}-\beta^{\prime}s_{t})\mathbf{1}(d_{t}=1))-\Sigma_{\varepsilon}.$$
But $f_t$ does not appear in the equations above. Doesn't this mean to solve for $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\Sigma_{\epsilon}$ one does not actually need the kalman filter? Can anyone explain this to me?

Possibly helpful https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78287/

This model $$y_t=\beta's_t+\gamma d_tf_t+\varepsilon_t,$$ is it also having some sort of autocorrelation or are the measurements (the $y_t$?) at different $t$ independent?

@SextusEmpiricus I think the $y_t$'s are i.i.d..

I do not know so much about Kalman filters but often it is relating to some dynamic system where values in the past influence values in the future. In this equation it seems like an ordinary regression problem with heteroscedasticity because you have two sources of error, $f_t$ and $\epsilon_t$ and all points in time are like independent samples. If you destroy the time labels in the data, then it has no influence on the equations.
